# How to add custom variables in SugarCRM for email templates?

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I would like to define new variables for the email template editor.

For example, now I can use "$account_name" and it is replaced by the Account Name value.
I would like to define in a place of the PHP code things like $end_subscription, being $end_subscription calculated in the PHP code based on creation date.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Pro Version of Sugar:

Have you tried to add a calculated Field to the Module?

You don't have to use it in a view. It would show in the Template creation anyway.

With CE you could try:

Create a non-db field of type "function"

```
'field_name' => array ( 
   'name' => 'field_name', 
   'vname' => 'LBL_FIELD_NAME', 
   'type' => 'function', 
   'source' => 'non-db', 
   'function_name' => 'function_name', 
   'function_params' => array('date_modified'), 
   'function_params_source' => 'this', 
   'function_require' => 'custom/modules/Accounts/Calculate.php', 
),
```

It will show in the Template creation. I don't know if the field will be filled for an email  you would have to try that...